# display: none CSS code does not effect several Divs in mobile Safari (on iPad)

Tags: css, ipad, visibility

I have a website that will be loaded in a web frame of an iPad app, so I have created a separate CSS file for the iPad, which is automatically loaded by a user agent call.  Nothing too difficult here.

The problem is that 2 divs are not responding to the display:none CSS.  The sidebar and the footer are still showing, despite being specifically called in the CSS just the same as all of the other elements, which are hidden correctly in Safari on the iPad.

[www.themonitorgroup.com/disclaimer.html](http://www.themonitorgroup.com/disclaimer.html) is a good page to illustrate this issue.
[www.themonitorgroup.com/css/ipad.css](http://www.themonitorgroup.com/css/ipad.css) is the specific CSS file for the ipad.

I assume there is something stupid simple I am missing.  Please let me know if you can find anything.  Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Even though you have a CSS sheet just for iOS, you're still including your main CSS sheet at `css/main.css`.  It's likely something in `main.css` over-riding it.

Answer (score 1):

Validators are [your friend](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.themonitorgroup.com%2Fcss%2Fipad.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en). You're missing a closing brace here:

```
#mainnav {
    display: none;
```

And you have `#sidebar` rather than `.sidebar` in the style sheet.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  I actually had mainnav correctly defined, however I included a SECOND definition, which as you pointed out, was invalid.  Footer does need to be called as the Div, not the class though.  As always with CSS, one mistake ripples through.  Once I removed the duplicate, invalid Mainnav call, everything worked out.  Thank you so much.